# Merge Numerical Data Query MS Access

Tags: ms-access-2007

I've been asked to combine data from various columns into one column. However the SUM function:

```
NewValue: Sum([Value1]+[Value2]+[Value3])
```

Merges the data together, e.g if there are 100 lines per column, it merges to one single answer:

```
Value1 Value2 Value3
10     20     30
10     25     35
```

Will show as:

```
NewValue
130
```

When I want it to show as:

```
NewValue
60
70
```

I hope that's clear? I'm not very good with Access, so this role has sort of been dumped on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to add columns in the same row (but not over more than one row), you don't need `Sum()` at all:

```
select Value1 + Value2 + Value3 as NewValue
from YourTable
```